# WC()->shipping->get_packages() returns empty array

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to loop through my WooCommerce shop's shipping methods. I have tried with this peiece of code, as recommended elsewhere:

```
WC()->shipping->get_packages()
```

However, it returns an empty array. Shipping is enabled and works fine on my shop though.

How come? And what can I do to retrieve enabled shipping methods?

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
wc()->shipping->load_shipping_methods();
```

Works